# yii2 onchange add or remove js core validation

Tags: javascript, yii2

On the change of dropdown,

```
if(1){
    div.show();
}
if(2){
   div.hide();
}
```

this div contains, the form is getting displayed with the main form, so when I tried to save with div.hide(), it is not saving coz hidden div containing the required field.
The model is used to create a field in toggle-able div has required, I want to keep this required since I am using in different place.
So how do I remove and add core js validation on change?

Answer (score -1):

By using display css you can handle the required field. When input field has display none than required attribute is neglect.

```
if(1){
    $("div").css("display","block");
    // or used with id
    // $("formDiv").css("display","block");
}
if(2){
    $("div").css("display","none");
    // or used with id
    // $("formDiv").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: it won't save since the attribute is still available but it is hidden.